# Basemap disappears when adding shapefile in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-pro, basemap

I have an issue using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.1.

The basemap is disappearing when I load in a shapefile.

It is funny because I did once and it worked just fine. I just wanted to change the map projection to be centered over the Pacific Ocean, which I didn't manage to do, and I think I might have "broken" something.
Because now I want to just load again the shapefile and work with it, even if it is not centered where I want it to be, and it keeps losing the basemap.

Do you have any idea why this is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: What projection did you set the map to? What projection is your shapefile in? Or even better, could you share your data? It's hard to know what is going on without more info.

Comment: It seems likely that the projection of the canvas and shapefile no longer are compatible, and that the basemap server is confused by requests outside its map extent/scale support.

Comment: I downloaded the shapefile from here: https://www.worldwildlife.org/publications/marine-ecoregions-of-the-world-a-bioregionalization-of-coastal-and-shelf-areas

It's projection is PROJCS["WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere" which is the same as the projection of my basemap. So this can't be why the basemap is disappearing when I load the shapefile.

Comment: What happens if you click the back (left arrow) button in the 'Map' tab on the ribbon?  Does it return to that previous map extent and show the basemap for that extent?

Comment: Somehow today it worked. I really don't know why and what happened. I did the same things as yesterday and the basemap didn't disappear.